# How to select a path tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have made a Box Plot chart (Highcharts) , Here's my example:

https://jsfiddle.net/hew8nq5u/

My code is:

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {

        chart: {
            type: 'boxplot'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'All Patients'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Asia Pacific', 'Europe', 'Latin America', 'North America', 'SWAC'],
            title: {
                text: '      '
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Annual Center Volume 2016'
            },
            tickInterval: 5,
            min: 0,
            max: 75
            //plotLines: [{
            //    value: 932,
            //    color: 'red',
            //    width: 1,
            //    label: {
            //        text: 'Theoretical mean: 932',
            //        align: 'center',
            //        style: {
            //            color: 'gray'
            //        }
            //    }
            //}]
        },
        //colors: ['#91e8e1', '#7cb5ec', '#434348', '#90ed7d', '#f7a35c',
        //         '#8085e9', '#f15c80', '#e4d354', '#2b908f', '#f45b5b', ], //updates default colors
        plotOptions: {
            boxplot: {
                fillColor: '#F0F0E0',
                lineWidth: 2,
                upperQuartileColor: 'green',
                lowerQuartileColor: 'green',
                medianColor: '#0C5DA5',
                medianWidth: 3,
                stemColor: '#A63400',
                stemDashStyle: 'solid',
                stemWidth: 1,
                whiskerColor: '#3D9200',
                whiskerLength: '20%',
                whiskerWidth: 3                 
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Region Runs',
            showInLegend: false,
            //colorByPoint: true,
            color: 'red',
            data: [
                [2, 4, 18, 43, 53],
                [5, 9, 16.5, 32, 52],
                [1, 3, 6, 11.5, 21],
                [3, 9, 20, 38, 73],
                [1, 2, 8, 16, 20]
            ],
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>'
            }
        },
        {
            name: '75th Percentile',
            type: 'line', 
            color: 'red',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            },

        },
        {
            name: 'Median',
            type: 'line',
            color:'#0C5DA5',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            },

        },
        {
            name: '25th Percentile',
            type: 'line', 
            color: 'red',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            },

        },
        {
            name: '90th percentile',
            type: 'line',
            color: '#3D9200',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            },

        },{
            name: '10th percentile',
            type: 'line',
            color: '#3D9200',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            },

        }//,
        //{
        //    name: 'IQR',
        //    type: 'line',
        //    color: 'brown',
        //    marker: {
        //        symbol: 'square'
        //    },

        //},
        //{
        //    name: 'Outlier',
        //    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        //    type: 'scatter',
        //    data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
        //        [0, 128],
        //        [1, 161],
        //        [2, 58],
        //        [3, 204],
        //        [4,42]
        //    ],
        //    marker: {
        //        fillColor: 'white',
        //        lineWidth: 1,
        //        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        //    },

        //    tooltip: {
        //        pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
        //    }


        //}
        ]

    });
```

I would like to have top of the box and bottom of the box in different colors, and also top of the whisker and bottom of the whisker in different colosr for each box (region). But all of the lines in the box are in the same color (red) and top and bottom of the whisker are in the same color (green).

I've found currently it's not possible in highcharts to have box bottom and top in different colors. Same with top and bottom whiskers. Because of that, I want to resolve the issue, by selecting the element "path" (its class) using jQuery and appending html in it to change the color in yellow. Something like this:

```
$(".highcharts-boxplot-whisker").append("<path fill='none' class='highcharts-boxplot-whisker' stroke='yellow' stroke-width='3' d='M 59.1 80.5 L 71.9 80.5'></path>");
```

But something is wrong with my selector, nothing happened. How can I do this? Thank you in advance for any help. [The tag that I want to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iyCQ.png)

Comment: Searching for "manipulating svg" gives lots of existing questions, please check those first before posting your own.

Comment: You can use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer) to render the line in the graph. The information about the whiskers/step position can be gathered from the point object. Those values can be translated to pixels (with axis.toPixels). See example http://jsfiddle.net/coo8bcuq/

Comment: Thank you very much :). But when I copy the code for events to my code, I've got a lot of syntax errors. Also, please show how to achieve the top of the box and the bottom of the box? Please show. Thank you again :)

Comment: Why my Highcharts don't recognize the renderer? I have the same version as in the http://jsfiddle.net/coo8bcuq/ is.

Comment: It might because this refers to a different object in your event handler. On redraw, the errors might be prevent if the whiskers will be hidden instead of destroyed. For colouring top and bottom, you can grab point.q1 and point.q3 values - box can be only covered with the new created lines unless you want tot destroy the whole box. http://jsfiddle.net/coo8bcuq/1/

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my life :) Best regards, nean0502

Answer (score 0):

You can change borders using jQuery [css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/) ! :)

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $("div").css("border-top", "5px solid blue");
  $("div").css("border-bottom", "5px solid red");
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and interest. But, I can't make a selector, it is a path tag with a color. Please check the jsfiddle link. Thank you again.

Comment: I am not familiar with Highcharts but as we can see in the Highcharts Options Reference (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/) , there is no option to custom specific border... But I don't know if there are any ways to do that. Plus, I could not select the boxes, if you can, you owned it. Good Luck (y)